# Run Xcode Bot trigger script on development machine

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-bots

I'd like to trigger a system notification on my development machine when my Xcode Bot begins testing. I've got the notification working, but it presents on the testing server instead. (In my case, that's actually a different login on my dev machine.)

Here's my pre-integration script:

```
#!/bin/sh

osascript -e 'display notification "Integration starting!" with title "Xcode CI"'
```

How can I get this script to instead run on my development machine? Thanks for reading.